# IntegerUpDown Keyboard Input Ignored

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I'm using the latest version of Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll and I'm having an issue with the IntegerUpDown as well as the DoubleUpDown. I'm unable to enter values through the keyboard. Only the mouse is allowed to change values.

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown x:Name="UpDownQuantity" Increment="1" Height="22" Width="85" ValueChanged="UpDownQuantityOnValueChanged"/>
```

Is there something specific I need to add to allow keyboard input either through number pad or number row on keyboard?

Comment: Have you got a small test project that demonstrates the issue ?

Comment: @netniV the issue was I'm calling and showing the WPF window from WinForms. In order to pass the input to the WPF controls, you have to call ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow). [Example](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/open-a-wpf-window-from-winforms).

Comment: You should put this into an answer and mark it as the accepted answer in case others need it :)

Comment: I don't have enough points to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may not read comments the op solved this himself :

@netniV the issue was I'm calling and showing the WPF window from WinForms. In order to pass the input to the WPF controls, you have to call ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow).